# wordpress site image served by smush plugin load very slow, how to make wordpress image load faster?

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website, I use smush plugin to load some images, but the image served by smush always pending, is there anyway to imporve the loading speed of images?

for smush plugin, it is supposed to reduce the image size to make the images load faster.

The site for reference
https://www.ahotech.com/

screen shot of problem:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to make the images load faster,for example:

1. Serve your images over CDN
2. Use webp version of image
3. Resize Images Before Using Them
4. Compress Images To Save Even More Size
5. Enable Browser Caching For Your Site

if the smush plugin does not work well, you can try another ones like **EWWW Image Optimizer**